# Homological algebra is linearized homotopical algebra?

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

I have stumbled across statements like

> - Homological algebra is linearized homotopical algebra.
> - Chain complexes are linearizations of simplicial complexes.

The Dold-Kan correspondence was often mentioned as well. Unfortunately, I don't understand it, and would have never imagined there was such a thing at all...

So what do the above statements actually mean? In what sense is the word linearization being used?

Comment: By the Dold-Kan correspondence, chain complexes are simplicial abelian groups. These are precisely the objects you get when you linearize simplicial sets (by which I mean, in this case, taking levelwise free abelian groups). This is a simplicial model of the process of taking singular chains on a space, which computes its homology.

Comment: If you work with simplicial *sets*, rather than simplicial complexes, the idea is clear, as the comments suggest. Given a simplicial set $X$ we can take the free abelian group functor $\mathbb Z[X]$, which yields a simplicial abelian group. From this simplicial abelian group you can define a chain complex with the same sequence of abelian groups and alternating sums of face operators as differentials $d=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^id_i$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan why does taking levelwise free abelian groups deserve the name linearization? Is it just because freeness allows to "extend by linearity"?

Comment: @Exterior: in my simple mind anything where you start with something, then wave a magic wand and end up with something else where you can perform addition, should be called "linearization". I don't think ALL linearizations should be shadows of some unique uberuniversal categorical machine, but they all usually simplify the problem at hand (eg taking homology of a space remembers only a good chunk of it, and only up to homotopy).